# Script for searching sites with specific AD groups

Tags: 2010, powershell, groups, script

I have to get the list of sites which are using any of the 3 sharepoint AD groups. Here is function responsible for this:

```
function Search-Groups ($Web, $FilePath)
{
    try
    {
        foreach($User in $Web.Users)
        {
            if($User.Name -eq "GLOpRED-SP_LT" -Or $User.Name -eq "GLOpRED-SP_PPDA" -Or $User.Name -eq "GLOpRED-SP_GPM")
            {
                Write-Output $Web.Url | Out-File $FilePath -append
                break
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Given groups are not being used in $($Web)"
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "An errorr occured when trying to access groups: $_" 
    }
}
```

The problem is, that it didn't found any sites with those groups, despite that they exist. Anyone has an idea what is wrong with this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Name" of the SPUser (in this case AD Group) isn't necessarily the same as the "LoginName".

Run the following query to see the AD groups on a particular web. This will point you in the right direction:

```
$Web.Users | ? { ($_.IsDomainGroup) } | select Name, LoginName
```

It might be that the "Name" you're querying is totally different.